# CSS height, centering, and margin issues

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a page that has 0 margin from the top and bottom. But for some reason, I cannot get everything to stick to the top and bottom. There also is a `height` issue: although I have `height:100%;` for everything, the height of the `<div>`s exceed the height of the window.  Also, the content is not centered in the screen when the screen size increases (when it is larger than 1366*768, for instance).

The page has three columns with `float:left;`, wrapped in a `<div>` tag.
I have mainly such an `html` code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="col" id="col1"></div>
    <div class="col" id="col2"></div>
    <div class="col" id="col3"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS I have that modifies these is:

```
body, html {
    background-color: darkgray;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


#wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #666;
    color: white;
    min-width: 722px;
    max-width: 1119px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px black;
}


.col {
    /*background-color: red;*/
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: 0.6667%;
    margin-left: 0.6667%;
}

#col1 {
    width: 24%;
}

#col2 {
    width: 48%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
}

#col3 {
    width: 24%;
}
```

You can see the page [here in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JN8Cs/).

I want to get the `<h1>` (the darker gray area) to stick to the top, as well as the other `<div>`s that are the columns.  I also want the height to be the screen size, unless the second heading is clicked, in which case I want the div heights to increase to extend the dark gray area to the bottom of the last line of text.  I also want to center the whole thing, which fails to center when the screen size increases.

Comment: you can't use % values and px values together.Please use one standard.

The orientation problem while zooming is caused by this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the `padding: 10px;` in the `#wrapper` `<div>`  that causes the gap on the top. Removing that stuck the `<div>`s to the top of the page.  Also adding `margin: 0 auto;` to the `#wrapper` centered the the `wrapper` div on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JN8Cs/2/)**

**css**
*{

```
margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
    body, html {
        background-color: darkgray;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/JN8Cs/

Add 'clearfix' to #wrapper and remove the 100% height of #wrapper & body

```
.clearfix:after {
content: ".";
display: block;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
line-height: 0;
height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
height: 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I have update your css property like **#wrapper** I just Add display:table;

 #wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #666;
    color: white;
    min-width: 722px;
    max-width: 1119px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px black;
   display:table;
}
```